# В каком порядке вызываются слоты?

Tags: c++, qt, сигналы-слоты

Если к одному сигналу подключены множество слотов, то в каком порядке оны вызываются?

Comment: В порядке подключения и вызываются

Comment: этот ответ на чем основан?

Comment: https://webhamster.ru/mytetrashare/index/mtb0/143685408911cby2u1tr -- в версии qt4.x слоты вызываются в произвольном порядке

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ, офф документации я больше доверяю чем другому сайту (вашу ссылку не смотрел)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Согласно документации для [Qt 4](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#signals), [Qt 5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals), [Qt 6](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html#signals):

> If several slots are connected to one signal, the slots will be
> executed one after the other, in the order they have been connected,
> when the signal is emitted.

Перевод (машинный):

> Если несколько слотов подключены к одному сигналу, слоты будут
> выполняться один за другим, в том порядке, в котором они были
> подключены, когда излучается сигнал.